# Rails: Stylesheets/Javascripts work in Dev, not Prod

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

As a RoR newbie I've been reading/trying to understand how the asset pipeline works, and how it affects development vs. production when it comes to making my stylesheets/javascripts available to my app, but I'm still confused.

In my app, I call frequently used CSS/JS files from my application.css/.js files, and then explicitly call other .css/.js files as needed, for example:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'reset.css',"application",'bootstrap.min.css', 'bootstrap-responsive.min.css','font-awesome.css','http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,600,700', 'fancybox.css' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", 'modernizr.js', 'bootstrap.js'%>
```

This works just fine in development, but once I push my code to production, the explicitly called .css/.js files no longer work.  If I view source, I see that the files are being properly called into the page.

What step(s) am I missing in order to make this work in production? Thank you for your time and assistance.

UPDATE:
Per Martin M's suggestion, I added in the .css/.js to my config/environments/production.rb.

For example:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(reset.css grepfrut.css jquery-ui.css base-admin.css reports.css signin.css daterangepicker.css bootstrap.min.css bootstrap-responsive.min.css font-awesome.css fancybox.css)
config.assets.precompile += %w(modernizr.js bootstrap.js ddsmoothmenu.js wice_grid.js date.js daterangepicker.js signin.js)
```

I then re-precompiled and while I see the files in my public/assets, the javascripts are still not working, and some of the CSS doesn't work in Chrome.  I've tried clearing everything out of the browsers and still trying Chrome, Firefox and Safari doesn't work.

Not sure if its worth mentioning, but I'm currently forced to run this in Ruby 1.8.7-p370 due to my hosting provider.  I'll be moving to a more RoR-friendly provider later.

Thanks again.

Comment: It might be stupid to ask but did you run `rake assets:precompile` before?

Comment: Do I need to do this every time in production?  Such as when I edit/add .css/.js?

Comment: I just ran it in production.  Some of the styles are now showing correctly, but my javascripts are still missing.

Comment: Did you precompile it locally or on the production server? The precompile task creates an "assets" directory in public/. If you've done that locally, than there might be a conflict with the app/assets directory. It's mainly better to precompile on the production server.

Comment: I deleted the assets directory in production and re-ran precompile.  I'm still missing the .js files (and some of the .css).  For example, if I view-source, I see:/assets/daterangepicker-0cf08ceb2e42a13375d1e217fa200b69.js but this file isn't in public/assets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assets (js and css) that are not loaded by `application.css` and `application.js` are **not** automatically compiled by `rake assets:precompile`.

You have to explicitly include them by saying in `config/environment/production.rb`:

```
  config.assets.precompile += %w(reset.css bootstrap.min.css bootstrap-responsive.min.css font-awesome.css fancybox.css)
  config.assets.precompile += %w(modernizr.js bootstrap.js)
```

There is a commented example in the generated `production.rb`.

This is a bit confusing, because in `development` the assets are loaded any way.
And yes, you have to run `rake assets:precompile` every time you change a bit in your css/js.

Comment: thanks.  Please see my update above and let me know what else I may be able to do.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Do you see any errors in your JavaScript console in Fireforx/firebug, Chrome etc. ? Also check the network panel of firebug.

Comment: I looked at firebug network both locally and in production. there are a few missing .js files from the prod calls, but these files are usually added via gems.  Do I need to explicitly add them in as well? thanks.

Comment: I tried adding some of them explicitly (for example: jquery-1.9.1.min), but no luck.  Its also in my application.js file, but still doesn't show up via firebug

Comment: Ok..I was able to get the .js files to show up in Firebug (network), by adding, config.assets.compress = false to my production.rb, but the files still don't work.

Comment: After a bit more searching through the .js files and setting compression = false, I was finally able to get them to load/work correctly.  Thanks.

Comment: This looks like you included the files in `application.js` already, then they are combined in the one big application.js and not generated separately. So you can't reference them separately (and don't need to)

Comment: Thanks for this. I have spent hours trying to figure out why my css files were not working in production. And finally found this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably run `rake assets:precompile` in order to make it work in production.